# Entity Framework database-first and column attribute does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.2

I have a database with the constraint that all primary keys end with `_Id`. For my EF classes, I wanted to omit the underscore so I changed the T4 template for the generation of properties to this (`CodeStringGenerator.Property`):

```
public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    var dbName = _code.Escape(edmProperty);
    var propResult = "";

    if(dbName.Contains("_"))
    {
        propResult = "[Column(\"" + dbName + "\")]\r\n\t";
        dbName = dbName.Replace("_", "");
    }

    return propResult + string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
        dbName,
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
}
```

This removes all "_" from the property name and writes a column attribute to the property. But it seems like this breaks EF. With the column attribute, EF throws an exception every time I try to make anything like selecting an entity.

The exception is:

> The entity type *ENTITY* is not part of the model for the current context.

If I write the original name like in the database it EF will work with the entity but not if I add the column attribute.

Is there any way to rename all properties or make the column attribute work? 
Using EF6.2

Comment: Are you refering to the t4 template that generates an EDMX and entity classes? If not, I assume you work code-first, so you can use *code-first custom conventions* to achieve what you want.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes i refer to the t4 templates used to generate my entities in the _Database First_ strategy ... as written in the header of this topic.

Comment: Then you're out of options. When working database-first, data annotations are ignored. The mapping information in the EDMX prevails. To my knowledge there's no way to intervene in how entity framework tools in Visual Studio write the EDMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afters some *days* of researching i did not found a way other then using AutoMapper for OneWay transformation of Column to Entity.Property names so i decided to switch my ORM to a simpler one that works Primary with the Database First approach.

Conclusion: Not Possible